# How to use a Map<String,Object> as if it was just a simple Map

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to work on jdbctemplate. Reading [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/), I've reach part 2, which uses the code `List<Map> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);`. When I try to implement it in my code, `eclipse` forces me to use `Map<String,Object>` instead of simply `Map` as in the tutorial.

I'm new to java so I don't know how to access my database columns when it's `Map<String,Object>`.

How do we do that ?

Is the code below okay ?

```
List<Map<String,Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
    for (Map<String,Object> row : rows) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustId((Long)(row.get("CUST_ID")));
        customer.setName((String)row.get("NAME"));
        customer.setAge((Integer)row.get("AGE"));
        customers.add(customer);
    }
    return customers;
```

**Update**

Below is the error I get with this code

> type Exception report
>
> message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String
>     com.projet.testjdbc2.ArticleDAO.listerLesArticles(ArticleDAO.java:20)
>     com.projet.testjdbc.HomeController.home2(HomeController.java:78)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Because that is better. That tutorial uses raw types. Long outdated bad practice.

Comment: Does this code run correctly?

Comment: @JavaGuynextdoor Nope it does not. It says something like `BigDecimal` to `String` conversion error somewhere....as if I as using a number as a string or the inverse...That is what is happening

Comment: @Bloomberg58 Please write here the error message you are getting.

Comment: @JavaGuynextdoor Please see yhe update in my OP with the information you asked about

Comment: 'Says something like ...' is not an acceptable problem description, anywhere, let alone here. You wouldn't accept that from a customer. Don't try it here.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to believe that any of these fields is a `BigDecimal` to begin with, but whichever it is, *don't cast it to* `String`: cast it to `BigDecimal`. Obviously.

It doesn't have anything to do with `Map` *versus* `Map<String, Object>`.